# does PHP have a function like matlab's linspace?

Tags: php

I want this to execute the following code in PHP

```
linspace(1,7,4);
```

I want to have linear array list as an output.

Comment: "I want to have an array of linear array list". Use the kerfluffle to pondicate the three numbers.

Comment: if u know the mathematical meaning of `linspace` please write a function of your own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function linspace($i,$f,$n){
    $step = ($f-$i)/($n-1);
    return range ($i,$f,$step);
}

$test = linspace(0,3.14159,8);

print_r($test);
```

I have written my own in some minutes. Please test it out.

Answer (score 0):

function `range` is your friend:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

```
range(0, 12); //array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
```